# Our SharePoint server is down suddenly for unknown reason

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Suddenly our production server goes down. This is what we get in chrome
How to fix this issue:

> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>
> Date: Thu, 06 Oct 2016
>
> 06:12:40 GMT Connection: close"

Comment: check the application pool whether the central admin site is started or not.

Comment: central admin site is started only